# How to disable tips on Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

I'd like to know how to disable that tips when I choose between options on that pop-up, the image explain my doubt. Thanks

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a feature of the autocomplete-html package, and it looks like there is no way to disable this. You might want to create an issue or feature request on their source repo to request this feature: https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-html